# Do apache ignite REST APIs provide implicit locks?

Tags: rest, ignite

I want to perform get and put operations on an ignite cache using ignite REST APIs. In my application, multiple systems will be performing these operations simultaneously.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api

Comment: Does it work? Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cache writes and reads are safe to execute simultaneously from multiple threads or clients.